# How do we know cyclopentadienylmolybdenum tricarbonyl occurs as a dimer?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

Cyclopentadienylmolybdenum tricarbonyl, $\ce{MoC8H5O3}$, dimerizes to form the cyclopentadienylmolybednum tricarbonyl dimer, $\ce{(MoC8H5O3)2}$.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: Cyclopentadienylmolybednum tricarbonyl dimer]

How was it discovered that it does this?

If you had an sample of a pure substance, but didn't know if it had dimerized or polymerized, what information would you need to find out if it had?

Comment: Asking in general, makes it broad-_ish_  - there are various crystallographic, spectroscopic and "traditional" methods, to check out the structure.

Comment: $\ce{^{95}Mo}$ NMR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested answers from the textbook are to look at the output of a mass spectrometer, or to observe the macroscopic crystal structure.

However, NMR spectroscopy is also a perfectly acceptable way to go about it.

Comment: For reference: http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0567740868002773